# "push"-ing to array returns the length of it

Tags: javascript, arrays

The issue I have is that when I parse a JSON string, which correctlyreturns an array of elements, I try to push a new element to the array with empty values.

The problem here is:

```
console.log('addons ', this.categories[this.editingId - 1].addons);
console.log('parsed ', JSON.parse(this.categories[this.editingId - 1].addons));
console.log('pushed ', JSON.parse(this.categories[this.editingId - 1].addons).push({name:'', price:''}));
```

> addons is [{"name":"Peppers","price":50},{"name":"Pepperoni","price":150},{"name":"Chicken","price":250},{"name":"Cheese","price":150},{"name":"Broccoli","price":100},{"name":"Corn","price":75},{"name":"Extra Sauce","price":250},{"name":"Extra Meat","price":350}]

that the last argument returns an integer for the length of the array when it should log the array with the newly pushed element to it.

How can I successfully push to the array?

A minimal example is displayed here:
https://jsfiddle.net/L5p0ueqe/1/

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: why is there a whole bunch of `JSON.parse` anyway? It should have either been an object from the start or you should have converted it and saved it as the first step.

Comment: an example is added. @A.Lau because it's a JSON string stored inside a database that's not parsed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.push()` returns the length of the array. That is a documented feature. You ARE successfully pushing to the array. You just aren't successfully `console.log`ing the new value. When you `console.log()` this:

```
JSON.parse(this.categories[this.editingId - 1].addons).push({name:'', price:''}))
```

You will log the return value of `push()` not the array that was pushed into.

To fix this, you should save the result of `JSONA.parse()`, `push`, then `console.log`:

```js
let addons = '[{"name":"Peppers","price":50},{"name":"Pepperoni","price":150},{"name":"Chicken","price":250},{"name":"Cheese","price":150},{"name":"Broccoli","price":100},{"name":"Corn","price":75},{"name":"Extra Sauce","price":250},{"name":"Extra Meat","price":350}]';

var parsed = JSON.parse(addons)
console.log('parsed ', parsed);

parsed.push({name:'Caviar', price:'10000'})

console.log('pushed ', parsed);
```

Some documentation for `push()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Answer (score 1):

```
var addonsJson = this.categories[this.editingId - 1].addons;
console.log('addons ', addonsJson);
var addons = JSON.parse(addonsJson);
console.log('parsed ', addons);
addons.push({name:'', price:''})
console.log('pushed ', addons);
```

You need to store the array in a variable, modify it, then output the modified array.